# how to open Link url if className changes to display: block;

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to develop a function that will trigger a click on a link, but only if a classname is: display: block;

but I'm not advanced and I couldn't do it

what I got so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/thvinic/xesbvfkc/

```js
if ($('hidden').is('display') == 'block') {
document.getElementById("urlx").click();
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="HIDDENDIV" class="hidden">this is a div</div>

    <a href="https://www.google.com" id="urlx">Google go example!</a>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="path-para-seu-script"></script>
```

thanks for help!

Comment: Do you mean `$('.hidden').css('display') == 'block'` ?

Comment: Edit your question it is not understandable

Comment: The class `.hidden` is supposed to apply `display: block`? That is not intuitive or self-explaining. By default the element has `display: block`, how should it be hidden in the first place?

Comment: is that actually in my project it starts as display: none; then another script changes the .hidden class to display: block; that's where this last setting comes in, where I wanted when changing to display: block; the script caused a url to open.

I will try to apply this to a login check, so when someone logs in with the correct password and username, this link will always open, as I am storing it in localstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the `.hidden` property **display** with `.css` and inside the `click event` on link.

`e.preventDefault();` *// to prevent the default click*

`if ($('.hidden').css('display') == 'block') {` *//ask if .hidden display is block*

`$('#urlx').unbind('click');` *//Unbind the click for removing the preventDefault()*

In this example (`.hidden` is `display:none`) so the **click don't work**.
Change the `display:none` to `display:block` to make the link work.

```js
$('#urlx').on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if ($('.hidden').css('display') == 'block') {
  $('#urlx').unbind('click');
  document.getElementById("urlx").click();
}
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="HIDDENDIV" class="hidden">this is a div</div>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="urlx">Google go example!</a>
```

Edited!
**Automatic click:**
It waits 2 seconds and click!...

```js
setTimeout(function(){
if ($('.hidden').css('display') == 'block') {
  document.getElementById("urlx").click();
}
},2000);
```

```css
.hidden { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="HIDDENDIV" class="hidden">this is a div</div>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="urlx">Google go example!</a>
```

Comment: It didn't work when the class name is block, the link doesn't open automatically, but it helped me in another aspect.

Comment: I edited the answer to solve the automatically open link

Comment: Mark it as solver please.